# How do I get the Sony Small App SDK Sample Project to work?

Tags: android, sony

I have tried several times to get the Sony Small apps SDK Sample project but I can't get it to work:

Each time I use it I get the error:

> 06-02 10:40:13.358: E/AndroidRuntime(5903):
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved
>   to unexpected implementation

I have tried redownloading it from their website as well as from the sdk manager and it seems to have the same problem.  Anyone able to get it working?

Sample Project is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2690965/SmallAppSample.zip

Here is the main application class:

```
public class MainApplication extends SmallApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        /* Set the content of the application */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*
         * Set the content displayed when the application is minimized.
         * Calling this method is optional. If not called, application icon is displayed.
         */
        setMinimizedView(R.layout.minimized);

        /* Set the title of the application to be displayed in the titlebar */
        setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        SmallAppWindow.Attributes attr = getWindow().getAttributes();

        /* Set the requested width of the application */
        attr.width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
        /* Set the requested height of the application */
        attr.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height);

        /*
         * Set the minimum width of the application, if it's resizable.
         *
         * If you don't have strong intention to specify minimum window size,
         * it is preferable not to set minimum window size.
         * If you still want to specify the minimum size, set as small value as possible
         * to make your application work properly on the devices with small screens.
         */
//      attr.minWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_width);
        /* Set the minimum height of the application, if it's resizable */
//      attr.minHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_height);

        /* Use this flag to make the application window resizable */
        attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_RESIZABLE;
        /* Use this flag to remove the titlebar from the window */
//      attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_NO_TITLEBAR;
        /* Use this flag to enable hardware accelerated rendering */
//      attr.flags |= SmallAppWindow.Attributes.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;

        /* Set the window attributes to apply the changes above */
        getWindow().setAttributes(attr);

        setupOptionMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void setupOptionMenu() {
        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        final View optionMenu = header.findViewById(R.id.option_menu);
        optionMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainApplication.this, optionMenu);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menus, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainApplication.this,
                                R.string.menu_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });

        /* Deploy the option menu in the header area of the titlebar */
        getWindow().setHeaderView(header);
    }
}
```

Here is the Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.sony.smallapp.framework" />

    <service
        android:name="MainApplication"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.sony.smallapp.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Any help is really well received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine. I'd guess there's something wrong with the references. Hope this link helps. http://juristr.com/blog/2010/06/android-instrumentation-test/

Comment: Hi - Looks like it was the Sony Library.  I redownloaded it using the download from the website and added it as an external jar and it works. - Thanks Pete for helping to diagnose